# Paypal preapprove dates

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

When I set pre approval details (using SDK) by default it puts date that is now as a start date, and end date + 10 days.

As soon as I receive the PA Key, I confirm the payment, and try to execute PAY Api.

But then I get the following response:

> > [message] => The preapproval key can't be used before the start date or after the end date

Which is strange, because today is 2012-11-09.   MAchine is using UTC time.

When I use start date from yesterday, Payment works fine, although DOCS state I can not use it like that:

> startingDate -
>
> First date for which the preapproval is valid. It cannot be before today’s date or after the ending date.

### Additional Info:

PA Request:

> requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&cancelUrl=http://example.com/cancel&Preapproval.php&currencyCode=USD&endingDate=2012-11-19&maxNumberOfPayments=10&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=50.0&returnUrl=http://example.com/done&startingDate=2012-11-09&feesPayer=SENDER

PA Response:

> responseEnvelope.timestamp=2012-11-08T18%3A17%3A02.047-08%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Success&responseEnvelope.correlationId=a63f86411f2ba&responseEnvelope.build=4110101&preapprovalKey=PA-1AH67555CK6636515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh I think this is because you did not set the timezone in the start/ending dates. So if I'm not wrong - by default it uses pacific time zone (California) I think.

You can set the startingDate and endingDate in either Zulu or GMT offset formats. as in the following respective examples:
2010-09-10Z 
2010-09-10T17:24:03.874-07:00

Comment: in the value of the two params - see my comment above (2nd sentence).